# Post DTO to Spring Controller, parameters are null

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I am trying to Post a list of strings from my Javascript front end to a Spring Boot Controller, for some reason the post happens, but my values are null.  Is there anything obviously wrong with my code?

Front end:

```
let bemsidList = new Array()
bemsidList[0] = "3129426";
bemsidList[1] = "240540";
let postData = { bemsids: bemsidList};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/admin/delete-email", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    postData
}));
```

Wrapper:

```
public class EmailWrapper {
  List<String> bemsids;

  public List<String> getBemsids() {
    return bemsids;
  }

  public void setBemsids(List<String> bemsids) {
    this.bemsids = bemsids;
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(
  value = "/admin/delete-email",
  method = RequestMethod.POST,
  consumes = "application/json")
public String deleteEmail(@RequestBody EmailWrapper wrapper, Model model) {
  List<String> ids = wrapper.getBemsids();
  for (String s : ids) {
    EmailEntity emailEntity = emailRepository.findByOwnerBemsid(s);
    emailRepository.delete(emailEntity);
  }

  model.addAttribute("category", "admin");
  model.addAttribute("subCategory", "email");

  return "pages/index";
}
```

Debug - Breakpoint:

[image: breakpoint reveals getBemsids is null]

[image: ids is null]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation requestbody is used for restful applications & modelattribute for web mvc..you are mixing both and that is the issue here. Can you try changing requestbody with modelattribute and use form data instead xhr request to send data from frontend.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately adding quotes around the key doesn't seem to help.  I still get an empty EmailWrapper in my controller.  Here is the json data going to the backend: {"bemsids":["3129426","240540"]}

Comment: What is the annotations you are using, controller or restcontroller

Comment: The controller class uses the Controller annotation.  The method uses the RequestMapping annotation with method set to RequestMethod.POST

Comment: requestbody is used for restful applications & modelattribute for web mvc..you are mixing both and that is the issue here. Can you try changing request body with modelattribute

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  I changed up the dto on the front end and made it a FormData object, and replaced the RequestBody annotation with ModelAttribute and it seems to be working for me now.  If you edit your answer I will accept it.  Thanks!